# Error in an array, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

So, i'm using an array in my program, and it gives me this error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

The error is in fourth line of this code:

```
int n = numbers.length, numBigger10 = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (numbers[i] > 10)
                numbersBigger10[i] = numbers[i];               
                numBigger10++;
```

What can I do to solve?

If you want to know more details about the error please feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you please show the full code? Maybe the error is in the numbersBigger10 declaration

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this NullPointerException is because in your `if` statement you are trying to assign `numbers[i]` to an index location that is not present in the `numbersBigger10` array.

i.e. The two arrays, `numbers and numbersBigger10` have different sizes.

*edit* - It would be helpful to see more code though, specifically the part where you declared `numbersBigger10`.